# Error in Kivy "Revision format must be X.Y.Z[-tag]"

Tags: python, kivy

I try to run mi program but for some reason i see this error: "Revision format must be X.Y.Z[-tag]"
I dont know what it means.

I have been trying to take some things out of my code to know what is causing it but i havent figured it out yet

Here is my python file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
kivy.require("1.11.1")

class Inicial(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Inicial, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        temperaturaActual = "°C"


class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Inicial

if __name__=="__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

Here is my kv file:

```
#:kivy !

#:kivy !

<Inicial>:
    Label:
        id: "temperatura"
        text: root.temperaturaActual
        size_hint: (.25, .25)
        pos_hint: { 'center_x': .05, 'center_y': .55}
        font_size: 60sp
        font_name: 'C:/Users/mateo/AppData/Local/Microsoft/Windows/Fonts/Roboto-Light'
```

Comment: I edited the file, I changed it so you can see the error and reproduce it

Answer (score 2):

The `#:kivy` kv syntax is for declaring the minimum compatible Kivy version. You are declaring a version of `!`. As the error says, your version must be of the form `X.Y.Z[-tag]`, e.g. 1.11.0.

The simplest solution is to remove the `#:kivy` lines, they aren't necessary.

Answer (score 2):

The problem that you indicate is because you are incorrectly indicating the header in the .kv as [the docs](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html#syntax-of-a-kv-file) points out:

> ### Syntax of a kv File
>
> A Kivy language file must have .kv as
>   filename extension.
>
> The content of the file should always start with the Kivy header,
>   where version must be replaced with the Kivy language version you’re
>   using. For now, use 1.0:
>
> ```
> #:kivy 1.0
>
> # content here
> ```

In your case you use `#:kivy !` and you repeat it 2 times unnecessarily.

On the other hand you have other errors:

- Only the Property are accessible from the .kv, in your case current temperature is not.
- If you are going to indicate a measurement using the units, these should be as strings.
- The build method must return an object, not a class. In your `Initial` class which is a class, to return an object you must instantiate it using `Initial()`

Considering the above, the solution is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import kivy

kivy.require("1.11.1")

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty


class Inicial(BoxLayout):
    temperaturaActual = StringProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Inicial, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.temperaturaActual = "°C"


class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Inicial()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

```
#:kivy 1.11.1

<Inicial>:
    Label:
        id: "temperatura"
        text: root.temperaturaActual
        size_hint: (.25, .25)
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .05, 'center_y': .55}
        font_size: "60sp"
        font_name: 'C:/Users/mateo/AppData/Local/Microsoft/Windows/Fonts/Roboto-Light'
```