# I keep Getting This Error " raise Exception('Revision format must be X.Y.Z[-tag]') Exception: Revision format must be X.Y.Z[-tag]"

Tags: python, android, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I have tried to resolve this issue many times but still getting the same error.
I dont Know it is en error from ny code or some other error in installation but i have run kivy without using kv language and got output without error. iam getting error only while using kv.

Python Code

```
import kivy
kivy.require("2.0.0")
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty



class MyGrid(Widget):
   name = ObjectProperty(None)
   email = ObjectProperty(None)

   def btn(self):
      print("Name:", self.name.text, "email:", self.email.text)
      self.name.text = ""
      self.email.text = ""




class MyApp(App):
   def build(self):
       return MyGrid()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

KV Code:

```
#:kivy 2.0.0
<MyGrid>

    name: name
    email: email

    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        size: root.width - 200, root.height -200
        pos: 100, 100

        GridLayout:
            cols:2

            Label:
                text: "Name: "

            TextInput:
                id: name
                multiline:False

            Label:
                text: "Email: "

            TextInput:
                id: email
                multiline:False

            Button:
                text:"Submit"
                on_press: root.btn()
```

Comment: Should the line `<MyGrid>` end with a colon? `<MyGrid>:`

Comment: I tried but still showing the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it worked for me, but if it's still printing out errors, I think it's because of the missing colon in line 2 of your kivy file, as Iain suggested, and it should be:

```
#:kivy 2.0.0
<MyGrid>:

insert the rest of the code here...
```

Comment: I tried but still showing the same error. Is there a chance that i am getting an error beacuse of any installation mistakes?

Comment: That is probably the case... Try reinstalling kivy and everything? But before that can you provide us the full printed traceback error message? We can maybe figure out what's wrong with it, as only `raise Exception('Revision format must be X.Y.Z[-tag]') Exception: Revision format must be X.Y.Z[-tag]` isn't enough...

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "c:\Users\skris\Documents\Python\KIVY\DemoKV.py", line 31, in <module>
     MyApp().run()
   File "C:\Users\skris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 949, in run
     self._run_prepare()
   File "C:\Users\skris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 918, in _run_prepare
     self.load_kv(filename=self.kv_file)
   File "C:\Users\skris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 691, in load_kv
     root = Builder.load_file(rfilename)

Comment: File "C:\Users\skris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 306, in load_file
     return self.load_string(data, **kwargs)
   File "C:\Users\skris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 373, in load_string
     parser = Parser(content=string, filename=fn)
   File "C:\Users\skris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\parser.py", line 402, in __init__
     self.parse(content)

Comment: File "C:\Users\skris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\parser.py", line 508, in parse
     self.execute_directives()
   File "C:\Users\skris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\parser.py", line 414, in execute_directives
     require(version)
   File "C:\Users\skris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py", line 115, in require
     revision, tag, tagrev = parse_kivy_version(version)

Comment: File "C:\Users\skris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py", line 74, in parse_kivy_version
     raise Exception('Revision format must be X.Y.Z[-tag]')
 Exception: Revision format must be X.Y.Z[-tag]  ... Sorry its not alloeing me to print many words so i divided it in three parts.

Comment: I have done some researches and I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58546759/error-in-kivy-revision-format-must-be-x-y-z-tag), so have you tried deleting the `#:kivy 2.0.0` line?

Comment: yes i did unfortunately same results